# Windows Site-to-site VPN: One way traffic issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, site-to-site-vpn

Site 1:

- Windows 2008 R2
- It's the receiving side of the site-to-site PPTP VPN
- 192.168.1.4

Site 2:

- Windows 2003
- It's the dialing side of the site-to-site PPTP VPN
- 10.0.23.70

The VPN connects without issue, and once connected:

1. I can ping site 1 from site 2
2. I cannot ping site 2 from site 1

I assume there is some configuration to do on Site 1.

I have tried adding a route on Site 1 as follows:

```
route add 10.0.23.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.4 metric 1
```

This did not fix the problem.

Any ideas?

EDIT: It's a routing issue - not a firewall issue. All firewalls are disabled.

Comment: Ive had similar issues before and its always come down to something like one site does not allow pings? or although the route is in place the firewall on site 2 is blocking any traffic coming from the active VPN connection Site 1?

Comment: C:\>route add 10.0.23.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.4 metric 1
 OK!

C:\>tracert 10.0.23.70

Tracing route to 10.0.23.70 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1  DC01.my_domain.internal [192.168.1.4]  reports: Destination host unreachable.


Trace complete.


Any ideas?

There is no firewall in the way.

Comment: Out of interest where is this route being added on a workstation or on the DC01 (192.168.1.4)?

Comment: On DC01 itself. This is the only computer on Site 1 that I need to be able to access the Server on Site 2. I just need my domain controllers to be able to replicate.

Comment: I've had issues before between 2003 and 2008 R2... 

Firstly check 2008 R2 local firewall is off...

Then have a read of this article it maybe what your having issues regarding http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2008/11/07/unable-to-ping-the-tunnel-address-of-a-demand-dial-connection-on-windows-server-2008-rras.aspx

Comment: Your route seems wrong. Please add 'ipconfig /all' and 'route print' from both your DCs/RRAS servers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the route add syntax should be "route add 10.0.23.0 255.255.255.0 Site2TunnelEndpointIP".  You need to add a firewall rule to allow pings through the vpn tunnel. It is possible that the rule exists on one router only and not both. I am assuming Site 2 network is 10.0.23.0 (internal) and Site 1 is 192.168.1.0 (internal).